# how to use two grafana notification policy with multiple labels

Tags: grafana, alerts

I have grafana setup, and want to set a policy to get all the alerts generated for the namespace "myapp", However, I want to exclude alerts which are generated from the cluster "test-cluster".

below is my label setup
case-1

```
namespace=~myapp
cluster=test-cluster
```

this will not help, it still sends alerts from the cluster "test-cluster"

Case-2

```
namespace=~myapp
  |
  |  nested policy with below condition
   --> cluster=test-cluster
```

this also wont help, it give same result as case-1

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need nested policies for the use case you described (unless we're missing some additional context).

If using Grafana version 9x or later -

Create a notification policy, add the following two labels -

```
namespace=myapp
cluster!=test-cluster
```

Note: != above on cluster, you had specified =

Per the grafana docs - https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/fundamentals/annotation-label/labels-and-label-matchers/

"If you are using multiple label matchers, they are combined using the AND logical operator. This means that all matchers must match in order to link a rule to a policy."

You should get all alert notifications for namespace myapp which aren't from the test-cluster.